# How can set up my iPhone so that it is automatically in silent mode when I'm at the office?

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, focus

Is there a way to configure an iPhone such that it is automatically in silent mode at a particular physical location?

The obvious approach is to use Work focus mode, which I can easily configure to automatically activate when I am at my workplace.  But I can't figure out how to configure a focus mode so that it silences the ringer / notification sounds, *without completely suppressing the notifications themselves*.  I only want it to do exactly what it would do if I manually switch the physical switch to silent mode: that is, vibrate and show notifications and notification dots, but not make any sound.

Answer (score 2):

You're now able to do this on iOS 17 with the iPhone 15 Pro.

When you set up a Focus there's a new filter option that can turn silent mode on and off alongside the Focus.